# How do I get started with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I read the Amazon getting started guide, but still spent a long time falling into multiple pitfalls and scratching my head.
What is the best way to get my Dynamo DB project headed along the right path, so that I will not encounter performance or cost issues down the road?

Comment: While potentially helpful to some people, this is not really a question but a "How to get started" post

Comment: This type of post was within the Stackoverflow guidelines that were current at the time. I haven’t checked recently to see if they changed. Yes, you are right, this was never intended to be a question, but answers a bunch of questions that a newcomer wouldn’t even know how to ask.

Comment: Self-answered questions are acceptable, but then you'd have to separate it into one question and one answer.

Comment: Sure, I can split it up to keep within guidelines

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is purge your head of everything you know about relational databases. When designing a relational database you start with a model of the data then add indexes to support the queries you want to make against that model. In DynamoDB it's the other way round, you have to start by thinking about the queries you want to make, then structure the tables to make those queries efficient. In DynamoDB you also need to save multiple copies of data to make queries efficient, so the whole approach is totally different.

Fill the space you just made in your head with this concept. Imagine that your DynamoDB database has trillions of items (rows) distributed across a few thousand servers. Each server contains a few million items, and each item exists on only one server. Each time you query DynamoDB it will only send the request to one of the servers, so that server must contain all of the data that must be returned to satisfy your query. Read that again slowly and think about what it means for how you organize your data.

Note that this is a useful model to put in your head, but in practice DynamoDB keeps replica copies of items for reliability.

This means that if you want to return people by surname all of the people with the same surname must be stored on the same server. If you also want to return people by birth year then all the people with the same birth year must be stored on the same server. To satisfy both of these conditions at the same time you must store two copies of the data!

Since the results of each query must come from one server, you must store the data on servers based on how you intend to query it. The way that you tell DynamoDB this information is by setting partition key on each table. The partition key is the name of the attribute of your items that determines which server the item will be stored on. When querying the table you must pass the value you are looking for in the partition key so that DynamoDB knows which server to send the query to.

For example if you create a table of people with surname as the partition key, then all people with the same surname will be stored on the same server. This means that every time you query this table you must select items that exactly match on surname (so that all items in the result set come from the same server), therefore queries against this table can only return people with identical surnames.

If the partition key is not unique, then you must specify another attribute (sort key) that makes a unique value when combined with the partition key. In this case each server will store items sorted by the sort key and queries that select on this attribute will be efficient and cheap. To carry on with the person table example since surname is not unique you would need a sort key for the table and it would have to be something that is unique when combined with the surname - you could use a government issued ID or a GUID for example.

Note that it is not possible to store two items that have identical values for the partition key and the sort key, when adding the second item it will overwrite the first one.

At first this seems very restrictive but bear with me, we are not finished yet.

To recap, when you query the table the query execution happens in three stages.

You must specify an exact match on the partition key attribute. This is used to figure out which server contains the data.
Only one server handles the request. The data is physically stored in order of partition key and sort key on that server so matching records can be found efficiently using indexes. Your query doesn't have to match exactly on the sort key, you can use less than, greater than etc.
If your query selects on other attributes this is a filter in DynamoDB, and it is applied to all the items selected in step 2. Note that all of these items must be read from backing store, and you will be charged for them.
I have read suggestions online that you can make DynamoDB more flexible by adding an attribute that contains the same value for every item, and making this attribute the partition key, but think about what happens in this case. Firstly since all items have the same partition key value they are all stored on one server (remember that DynamoDB is designed for the case where you have billions of items spread across thousands of servers, that's how it scales). Secondly any queries that don't include the sort key will require a full table scan which will read all of those billions of items from the backing store even if only a few items match the query, and you are charged for each item read from storage, not for the items returned to your application.

Note that DynamoDB also has a scan function that sends a request to all of the servers and collates the results into one giant resultset. This is only for special cases like exporting all of the data, and should not be used in regular application programming.

Many applications need to query data in multiple ways without losing efficiency. DynamoDB provides two kinds of secondary indexes for this.

Local Secondary Indexes are similar to indexes on relational databases in that they provide an efficient way to find items based on a specific attribute, but they are different from relational databases because each server only indexes the items stored on that server. This means you have to select items matching the partition key of the underlying table (to select the right server) before matching on the secondary index. This means that if the partition key on your person table is surname, queries against all local secondary indexes can only return people that all have an identical surname.

Global Secondary Indexes are more like tables than Indexes because they contain a copy of the data they index. They have to contain a copy of the data because they have a different partition key from the underlying table, and the items are therefore indexed on different servers from the servers where they are stored. This also means that if you select items using a Global Secondary Index you can only return attributes that are included in the index. For example if you add a global secondary index to your person table partitioned by first name, then the duplicate person records for this index will be distributed across servers such that all the people with the same first name will be stored on the same server. Any queries against this index will always return people with the exact same first name.

Global Secondary Indexes must contain a copy of the partition key and sort key from the underlying table so that the index can be updated automatically when the table is updated. This involves copying the data to other server which takes time, and is why DynamoDB is eventually consistent.

Comparing relational databases to DynamoDB:

They can both scale horizontally for reads because relational databases can have read replicas.
DynamoDB will automatically scale to thousands of servers whereas having thousands of relational read replicas is not practical.
DynamoDB also scales horizontally for writes because the partition key determines which server stores each item.
Relational databases are much more flexible and powerful for ad-hoc queries.
The data in DynamoDB has to be structured to support very specific queries efficiently, but then it will execute those queries in single digit milliseconds even with trillions of items stored.
Have fun!!